# Set fallback value to display on page if URL parameter is blank

Tags: html, url, dynamic, parameters

I would like to populate a first name in the header of a webpage using a URL parameter. So if the URL is domain.com?name=Steve, the header would read: Hi there, Steve! I have the the below code working for that:

```
<html>
    <body>
       Hi there <span id="name"></span>!
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const name = urlParams.get('name');
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
</script>
```

How do I add a fallback value, say, "Hi there, Friend!", if the URL parameter is blank or missing altogether?

Thank you!

I've been unable to find a solution which works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can make either the name variable itself dependent on the URL parameter being not "null" or blank, or set the innerHTML based on the same.

For example:

```
const name = urlParams.get('name') !== null ? urlParams.get('name') : 'Friend';
    
// OR
    
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name !== null ? name : 'Friend';
```